# CSS3 Drop Shadow Making Td elements in IE Shift

Tags: css, internet-explorer

OK so I have a super simple webpage that has a table on it with each `<td>` tag being, for lack of a better term, a "button". Each `<td>` tag has an anchor tag with two `<div>` tags inside of it. I have a box shadow set up on each `<td>` tag's hover to show that you can click the link to display a modal window with more info. Everything works perfect in all browsers other than **IE**. I am using IE 9 and the `box-shadow` works but each time you hover over a `<td>` tag it shifts the other 14 elements. I will provide my code for the first `<td>` element but do not have a link since the site is in a testing environment on a local server. The style sheet for this page is also used for multiple other pages but i will only include the section that applies to this page. Cheers and thank you in advance for any help.

```
#tblSuccess{margin: o auto; border-spacing: 15px;}
.successTd{width: 140px; height: 180px;}
.successTd:hover{filter: progid:DXImage.Transform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#b0b0b0', Direction=135, Strength=7;}
.imageDiv{padding-left: 7px; padding-bottom:7px; padding-right:7px; float:left; Width:142px; background-color:#E1913A;}
.jobDiv{padding-left: 7px; padding-top: 7px; padding-right: 7px; padding-bottom: 1px; background-color: #EDBB7C; width: 142px; text-align: center; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; color: #000;}
.modalH1{font-family: 'Nothing You Can Do', cursive; font-size: 18pt;}
.modalP{font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 12pt; color: #D66E27;}
.modalH2{font-family: 'Nothing You Can Do', cursive; font-size: 11pt; color: #000;}
.close{float:right; padding:10px 10px 0 0;
/* Z-index of #mask must be lower than #boxes .window */
#mask{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; z-index:9000; background-color:#000; display:none;}
#boxes .window{position:absolute; width:440px; height:200px; display:none; z-index:9999; padding:20px; border: solid 5px #FFAF3F;}
/* Customize your modal window here */
#boxes #dialog1{width:425px; height:300px; background-color: #FBF4d8;}

<table id="tblSuccess" cellspacing="15px">
    <tr id="Row1" style="width: 925px; height: 180px">
        <td class="successTd">
            <a href="#dialog1" name="modal" style="text-decoration: none">
                <div class="imageDiv">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <span style="font-size: 10pt;
                        color: #FBF4D8; font-weight: bold;">Aaron C.</span><br />
                    <img src="images/LandingPages/SuccessStories/AaronChapman-Cashier.jpg" alt="Aaron C" />
                </div>
                <div class="jobDiv">
                    Cashier
                </div>
            </a>
            <div id="boxes">
                <div id="dialog1" class="window">
                    <h1 class="modalH1">
                        Aaron's story...</h1>
                    <p class="modalP" align="justify">
                        I worked as a cash vault clerk before I got to Centriq. I always loved computers
                        and I wanted to make I.T. a career instead of just a hobby. A friend had gone through
                        the track here at Centriq and recommended it to me. The teachers were always willing
                        to answer any questions we had, and were always challenging us to rely on ourselves
                        and our colleagues. It is completely different than anything I have done before.
                        I loved every minute of it.</p>
                    <h2 class="modalH2" align="center">
                        Track: IT Administrator</h2>
                    <h2 class="modalH2" align="center">
                        Old Job: Cashier &nbsp&nbsp New Job: Computer Operator</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="mask">
                    <a href="#" class="close">
                        <img src="images/ModalXImage.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the shadow on the **contents** of the TD, not the TD itself.

Another work-around may be to put an absolutely-positioned DIV in the cell and give it the shadow. This way it is unlikely to nudge the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but neither of those solutions will work in my situation.